# Exception：java.util.ConcurrentModificationException at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.checkForComodification

Tags: java, list, exception

I want to add some branch road to main road, so looping all roads, adding one road to the main.
Every time the `main_road` will change insteads of `roads`, But still throwing the blow Exception, Why the state of `main_road` will cause this?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:1169)
at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.get(ArrayList.java:993)
```

Here is my code:( ps: findPosition(final, final))

```
    // First, chose the main road
    int max = 0;
    List<TrackPoint> main_road = null;
    for (List<TrackPoint> road : roads) {
        if (road.size() > max) {
            max = road.size();
            main_road = road;
        }
    }
    roads.remove(main_road);

    // insert branch to main road
    for (List<TrackPoint> road : roads) {
        int head_insert_position = findPosition(road.get(0), main_road);
        main_road.addAll(head_insert_position+1, road);
    }
```

Comment: Can you describe the problem you're trying to solve, and the structure of `roads`? I've got an idea that you're managing to create an alias and that's getting you screwed up, but it's not clear to me what you're actually working with here.

Comment: - The problem is: I got the line combined by some sorted points of bus, but the order of points is not all right. So I decided to reorder the points to make the line reusable.                                      - The structure of roads is List<List<TrackPoint>>, and TrackPoint class is:    class TrackPoint { float longitude； float latitude;}

Comment: I suspect that what's happening is you've managed to arrange things so that `main_road == roads` - that would result in the concurrent modification exception that you're seeing. You could check this easily enough (for example, put in a line like `if main_road==roads System.out.println("Oops!");`

Comment: The type of roads is `List<List<TrackPoint>>` while main_road is `List<TrackPoint>`, finally, I will join all the items of roads together to make a longest new road.